# SVN: checkout access denied

Tags: linux, svn

I try to `svn co "valid url"` with the credential I have been given but I get errors:

```
svn: E175013: Access to '/RepoName' forbidden
```

What can cause this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN checkout command itself is not working. It means, even read operations are not permissible from this user account. Pls. check repository level access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an account on the SVN repository but not the rights to read that particular folder.

Comment: Thank you but I am supposed to have full rights on that particular folder (commit ... and so on)

Comment: @Kabyle supposed does not mean that you actually have them. Verify the URL for issues such as case-sensitivity and typos and contact your admin.